# How do I call methods when actionPerformed is called in GUI

Tags: java, events, user-interface, if-statement

Here is my ButtonListener class in my GUI. I have several buttons within it, that when clicked, I want to call a certain method for each one, for instance:

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ){
            if (event.getSource( ) == buttonA)
```

If button A is selected, I want to call a method and have its return statement displayed.

Comment: Sorry, my question is what would i put in this if statement to call my method from another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If I understand you correctly)

You could have

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == buttonA)
    {
        ButtonAImpl x = new ButtonAImpl();
        x.myMethod();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttonB)
    {
        ButtonBImpl y = new ButtonBImpl();
        y.myMethod();
    }
 }
```

You may want to look at some design patterns to help in this scenaro...

MVC - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

MVP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter

Comment: I wish it was that easy, if I simply put my method() it says cannot find symbol - method() =\ sorry im new to java

Comment: I made some edits, is that what you are looking for?
I strongly recommend reading into design patterns such as MVC or MVP for this situation. "Head First Design Patterns" is a fantasic book for learning (once you have the basics), I am reading it at the moment.

Comment: You said you had another class where you want to call a method from. So you would have "YourClass nameItAnything = new YourClass();".

Comment: wait no ButtonAimpl would be the name of the class I'm trying to take the method from correct?

Comment: No bother! I'm sure the answers here will help you get it working. All the best

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it, you should do the following (just an example):

```
class X{

  JButton firstButton;
  JButton secondButton;

  public X(){

   firstButton=new JButton("first");firstButton.setActionCommand("FB");
   secondButton=new JButton("second");secondButton.setActionCommand("SB");

  }//constructor closing

  public void method1(){}
  public void method2(){}

  class EventHandler extends ActionListener{

     public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

      String action=e.getActionCommand();

     if(action.equals("FB"))method1();
     else if(action.equals("SB"))method2();

    }//



  }//inner-class closing

}//calss closing
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is what would i put in this if statement to call my method from another class

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good practise to use a switch in this case because you've said you have several buttons.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   switch (e.getSource())
    case buttonA:
         buttonACode();
         break;
    case buttonB:
         buttonBCode();
         break;
    default:
         someDefaultAction();
         break;
 }
```

If you would like to display the returned result you can replace `buttonACode();` with `System.out.println(buttonACode());`